# Replace text in pipe

Tags: powershell

I have the following script I am using to delete git merged branches:

```
function Remove-MergedBranches
{
  git branch -a --merged |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } |
    Where-Object {$_ -NotMatch "^\*"} |
    Where-Object {-not ( $_ -Like "*master" )} |
    Where-Object {-not ( $_ -Like "*develop" )} |
    Where-Object {-not ( $_ -Like "*dev" )} |
    % {$_.replace("/remotes","")} |
    ForEach-Object { git branch -d $_ }
}
```

The `replace` is not working.

A branch might be `remotes/origin/tg-training-section`

Answer (score 3):

You wan't to replace `/remotes` in `remotes/origin/tg-training-section` which doesn't match (it doesnt start with a slash), so you probably want to omit the slash:

```
# ....
% {$_.replace("remotes","")}
```

Another way would be to replace `/remotes` and `remotes` by using `-replace` with a regex:

```
# ....
% {$_ -replace '\/?remotes'}
```

I would also consider to even use `\b\/?remotes` to ensure you don't replace `remotes` inside the string.